# Decoding JSON error "but found a dictionary instead"

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I'm making a history of today iOS app using the api http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/4/19

Here is the data struct of me:

```
struct HistoryAPIResponse: Codable  {    
    let data: [Events]
}

struct Events: Codable {
    let year: String
    let text: String
    let html: String
}
```

And here's how I fetch the data from it:`import Foundation
import UIKit

```
final class HistoryAPICaller {
    static let shared = HistoryAPICaller()
    
    struct Constants {
        static let topHeadLinesURL = URL(string:
            "http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/4/19"
            )
        
        static let searchUrlString =
        
        "http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/4/19"
        
        
    }
    
    private init() {}
        
        public func getTopStories(completion: @escaping (Result<[Events], Error>) -> Void) {
            
            guard let html = Constants.topHeadLinesURL else {
                return
            }
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: html) { data, _, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                
                else if let data = data {
                    do {
                        _ = try JSONDecoder().decode(HistoryAPIResponse.self, from: data)           
                    }
                    catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
            }
        }
            task.resume()
    }

    
    
    public func search(with query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Events], Error>) -> Void) {
        guard !query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        
        let urltring = Constants.searchUrlString + query
        guard let html = URL(string:urltring) else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: html) { data, _, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                completion ( .failure(error))    
            }
            
            
            else if let data = data {
                do {
                    _ = try JSONDecoder().decode(HistoryAPIResponse.self, from: data)    
                }
                catch {
                    completion (.failure(error))   
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

And in come one of the error message says:
typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I kind of understand the nature of the problem, that data is a dictionary. But I don't know how to solve it considering this is the structure of the API, that everything stores in the [data].

Any idea how to solve this issue? Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: `let data: [Events]` is wrong. Before accessing `Events` you see that in your JSON there is a key `Events`, it's missing a step.

Comment: ``struct HistoryAPIResponse: Codable  { let data: HistoryDataAPIResponse } struct HistoryDataAPIResponse: Codable  { let Events: [Events] }`` should do the trick. But it'd be better to name `let events` instead of let `Events` by setting custom coding keys, or key strategy. You could also use a custom `init(decoder:)` if you don't want that intermediary struct.

Comment: thanks for the help. the data turn out alright but now I'm experiencing troubles while returning the fetched data into tableView. I'm now using  do {let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(HistoryAPIResponse.self, from: data)
                        
                        print("Articles: \(result.data.count)")
                        
                   completion(.success(result.data))
                    }
                    catch {
                        
                        completion(.failure(error))
                        
                        
                    }

Comment: it says Value of type 'HistoryDataAPIResponse' has no member 'count' and Cannot convert value of type 'HistoryDataAPIResponse' to expected argument type '[Events]'

Comment: Now, it's `result.data.Events.count`

Comment: Thanks so much. I wish you a pleasant day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

```
struct Root: Codable  {    
    let data: HistoryAPIResponse
}

struct HistoryAPIResponse: Codable  {    
    let events: [Events] 
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case events = "Events" 
    }
}

struct Events: Codable {
    let year,text,html: String 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one works as well!